# Computing JSON diffs

Tags: java, json

Considering two JSON objects, how to compute the difference (subset) between them in Java ? I am currently using the `net.sf.json` lib;

I would be particularly interested in having a report like: JSON1 has these items that JSON2 does not have; Is there something built-in ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the tag that you are intending to use Java for this task.

What you can do is, have the JSON string parsed into Java domain objects, such as Student, Bus, Animal, or whatever your domain is, then overriding the equals and hashcode methods in your domain.

For example,

```
class Animal{
 private String name;

 public boolean equals(Object object){
  ...
 }

 public int hashcode(){
  ...
  // better to use Apache commons hashcodebuilder for this purpose
 }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, Java; The thing is that the JSON will only hold maps, arrays and primary types;

Comment: Jonier, your statement is somewhat T/F. You got to give us more details. For a start, you should see this tutorial what JSON and GSON can do for you. http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/